# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread : after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, java, systemd

We have a distributed Java search engine based on Lucene that normally runs as many processes which may each have their own thread pools on ~100 hosts, but we have a dev deployment that can run on a single 64GB dual hex-core workstation that we use for development.

We had been successfully running Ubuntu 14.04 on these dev workstations with high ulimit settings:

```
gada@C010390:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256189
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 51200
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256189
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

All the search engine processes are started by a script from a single process.

We recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and are now running into: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:  unable to create new native thread` errors when trying to start all the required processes.  I searched Google and saw posts about new resource limits being set by systemd, for example:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253903/creating-threads-fails-with-resource-temporarily-unavailable-with-4-3-kernel

I tried following this post and setting

```
DefaultTasksMax=infinity
TasksMax=infinity
UserTasksMax=infinity
```

in the following:

```
/etc/systemd/system.conf
/etc/systemd/user.conf
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

and rebooting but that did not seem to have any effect.

I checked dpkg and I appear to be running `systemd 229-4ubuntu7`.

```
gada@C010390:~$ dpkg -l systemd
...
ii  systemd                                  229-4ubuntu7              amd64                     system and service manager
```

According to this post:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/percona-cluster/+bug/1578080

the new systemd process limits were reverted in `229-4ubuntu6`, but I'm still having problems.

Can somebody please help me diagnose which system resource limit is preventing me from creating new Java threads in Ubuntu 16.04 and how to remove this limit?  I assume it is due to some systemd limit since that is the big difference between Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04, but I don't know that for sure and don't know what else in 16.04 could be limiting thread creation. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had identical problem and the root-cause seemed to be that logind.conf does not support "infinity". Instead you should use exact limit (such as `UserTasksMax=32000`).

It seems to be fixed in the latest version (https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3833), but at least our Ubuntu 16.04 had the version which didn't support `infinity`.

Comment: I wondered about that, but I saw people using infinity and unlimited in posts online.  Thanks very much for your response, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed that there was a new systemd logind task limit in Ubuntu 16.04 and that

```
UserTasksMax=infinity
```

was not being accepted in /etc/systemd/logind.conf as user Matti K suggested.  I changed this to

```
UserTasksMax=51200
```

to match the ulimit number of open files (the limit we changed in Ubuntu 14.04 to allow this setup to work) and everything works fine now.